# Styling Images from a chunk using css

Tags: css, laravel, chunks

I would like to displays images s in the image bellow
[image: Expected output]
I do know that I can use laravel `chunk()` helper function to achieve this which is what I have done but as bellow

```
    @foreach ($images->chunk(4) as $key=>$image)
            <div class="row">
                @foreach ($image as $item)
                @if ($key===0)
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div>
                        <span class="image-block block2">
                        <a class="image-zoom" href="{{ asset('uploads/property/large/'.$item->path) }}" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]">                         
                                <img src="{{ asset('uploads/property/small/'.$item->path) }}" class="img-responsive" alt="CEC Gallery"></a>
                    </span>
                    </div>
                </div>                        
                @else
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div>
                        <span class="image-block block2">
                        <a class="image-zoom" href="{{ asset('uploads/property/large/'.$item->path) }}" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]">                         
                                <img src="{{ asset('uploads/property/small/'.$item->path) }}" class="img-responsive" alt="CEC Gallery"></a>
                    </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    
                @endif
                @endforeach
            </div>
            @endforeach
```

this gives me the following result
[image: actual result]
From what you can see the rows not stopping at two and staking the remaining images as in the expected image. What could I be doing wrong or how could I do. The images could be as many as 200 and here I am just working with 12